# Cant print ArrayList in JSP from Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

So I have this simple list made in a java servlet, and I would like to display it within a JSP page. Servlet code:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException{


            ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

            myList.add("cat");
            myList.add("dog");
            myList.add("frog");
            request.setAttribute("list", myList);
            String nextJSP = "/index.jsp";
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
            dispatcher.forward(request,response);
}
```

}

However it won't print in the following JSP file:

```
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@page import="java.net.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.List" %> 
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@page language="java" import="myPackage.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<% List<String> myList = (ArrayList<String>) 
 request.getAttribute("list"); %>
<% out.println(myList); %>


 </body>

 </html>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: im getting a HTTP error 500 message, I have no idea why this is not working

Comment: OK, I have answered the question: let me know if it is working for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HTTP 500` error is come from this line:

```
<% List<String> myList = (ArrayList<String>) 
 request.getAttribute("list"); %>
```

It has extra `()`,remove it and make it as below,then the `HTTP 500` will diappear,instead you will got a warning `Type safety:Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList<String>`,but it doesn't matter

For how to print the ArrayList,if you have import `JSTL` tag in your jsp page,you can do it as below,previous answer has metioned:

```
<c:forEach var="li" items="${list}">
 <c:out value="${li}"/> 
</c:forEach>
```

If you do not want to use `JSTL`, you can use java code to print it:

```
 <% for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++){
   out.println(myList.get(i));
 } %>
```

Comment: Thanks, tried but still no luck. I believe this is something to do with my servlet, my jsp wont work if it's mapped in my web xml file

Comment: @kieron before I post my answer I have tested in my side and it works fine,so there must be something wrong with your project configuration

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your are having a HTTP 500 error message and I would suspect that it is coming from the following part of your code:

```
<% out.println(myList); %>
```

Keep in mind that the out used here is not System.out and does not behave the same way. Instead try (replace the line mentionned above by the following):

```
<%  Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {    
       out.println(<iterator.next());
    }
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use core tag foreach as

```
<c:forEach var="list" items="${YourList}">
 <c:out value="${list}"/> 
</c:forEach>
```